# opacity not working for img pointed by Hyperlink

Tags: image, opacity, hyperlink

In an asp.net applicaiton I am using Hyperlink which points to an image. On certain condition I am setting its
 "filter" property to  alpha(opacity=70) for IE
and "opacity" prop to 0.7  for Firefox 
so that it is shown dull to depict disable mode. This works fine in FIREFOX ie it shows dull in disabled mode but not in IE.

I see that the filter property is set on anchor tag and not on img tag present inside anchor. If I explicitly put the filter on image it works. But I am not able to do that programatically.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not already, I would create some on/off CSS classes for the filter and then dynamically change the class that gets assigned based on your conditions. Then you may want to try putting each link inside a div and assign the classes to the div tags.